# Как на Си определить массив строк в кодировке СР866?

Tags: c, массивы, кодировка

Мне надо на Си определить массив строк. Проблема в том, что строки должны быть в кодировке CP866, а код в windows-1251. Как определить массив

```c
    char* str[]={"строка СР866", "ещё"};
```

в данном случае?

Comment: Можно загружать данные из внешнего файла. Можно перекодировать на лету. Много чего можно. Вам зачем?

Comment: В память загружается массив char*, в нём ищутся совпадения с элементами массива str[] с помощью strcmp(). Хотелось бы самый простой способ.

Comment: Откуда этот загружаемый массив берётся?

Comment: Решение "в лоб" : использовать массив байт для текста, вместо функций начинающихся на `str` использовать те, что начинаются на `mem`. После чего можно байты отгружать туда, куда вам нужно.

Comment: @Sergey Gornostaev, массив в данном случае загружается из текстового файла.

Comment: @0Zerro я бы рекомендовал или сменить кодировку файла или менять кодировку загружаемых данных с помощью чего-нибудь типа iconv.

Comment: Использовать универсальную кодировку, через которую вести все преобразования. Хотя лучше делать иначе — пользоваться изначально юникодом, и лишь при необходимости перекодировать куда-то в legacy кодировки.

Comment: Я сделал так: загружаю файл со строками  в кодировке СР866, причём каждая строка соответствует элементу массива. Потом в цикле побайтно присваиваю массиву символы.

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете писать исходный текст программы в кодировке cp-1251. В том числе и строковые константы, которые потом будете использовать.

В программе заведите строковый массив точно такой же размерности, как исходный.

Обработайте все строки исходного массива с помощью ф-ции *iconv*. Смотрим *man 3 iconv*:

```
ИМЯ
       iconv - изменяет кодировку символов

ОБЗОР
       #include <iconv.h>

       size_t iconv(iconv_t cd,
                    char **inbuf, size_t *inbytesleft,
                    char **outbuf, size_t *outbytesleft);

ОПИСАНИЕ
       Функция   iconv()   преобразует   последовательность   символов   с   одной   кодировкой    в
       последовательность символов  с  другой  кодировкой.  Аргумент  cd  должен  быть  дескриптором
       преобразования,  созданным  ранее  с помощью функции iconv_open(3); дескриптор преобразования
       определяет кодировки символов, которые iconv() использует для преобразования. Аргумент  inbuf
       содержит  адрес  переменной, которая указывает на первый символ входной последовательности; в
       inbytesleft содержится количество байт в этом буфере. В  аргументе  outbuf  содержится  адрес
       переменной,  которая  указывает  на  первый  байт выходного буфера; в outbytesleft содержится
       количество байт в выходном буфере.
```

далее Вы можете открывать Ваш текстовый файл в кодировке 866 и искать в нём строки, заранее переведёные в кодировку 866.